# XPath predicate to select elements with an attribute with unknown value

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the example below I know how to select the name of the town based on the province attribute e.g. to extract "Riccione" I can use the following XPATH

//name[@province='Rimini']

```
<town>
   <name province="Rimini">Riccione</title>
   <italianProvince>Rimini</italianProvince>
</town>
```

But what if I don't know the value of the province attribute?
Is there a way to tell the XPATH to retrieve it from the element italianProvince?

Does something like the below exist?
//name[@province='//italianProvince']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
//name[@province=../italianProvince]
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you